# Can't send large json data via XMLHttpRequest - javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest, frontend

I need to pass a json variable as a paramater to a php script that will process the json data and store it in Database.

So first, in javascript, i was testing sending data like this :

```
$('#sendResult').load('http://localhost/myurl/phpFile.php?mrData=' + jsonArrFinal);
```

This was working well when passing small records (records can vary, it depends the data that user insert).

But when i increased the records, it started appearing this error in console:

```
414 (Request-URI Too Long)
```

I've changed the js code to:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/myurl/phpFile.php?mrData=' + jsonArrFinal );
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhr.send();
```

But still appearing the same error with POST method.
I've checked the json param and it has 5439 characters.

How can i resolve this? Thanks in advance.

*Please note that the length can be 8x more than 5439 characters.*

Comment: This reads as if you are using a "GET" request to update your database?

Comment: You are passing data in the URL which has a maximum size. Use a POST request and put the data in the body.

Comment: @JulianReschke yes but then i've changed the script to a POST method but still the same error. (i've made an edit to my question, adding this modification)

Comment: you didn't change the URL ('http://localhost/myurl/phpFile.php?mrData=' + jsonArrFinal) so you have the same problem , in POST you have to send jsonArrFinal in this way http.send(?mrData=.....);

Comment: Your URL is too long, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a GET request.

You're storing data, so you should be using a POST request anyway.

Use `$.post` instead of `$.load` and write your own logic to display the response in the `done()` handler.

---

> I've changed the js code to:

You need to put the data in the body of the request. POST requests don't change the rules for how much data you can put in the URL.

---

```
$.post("http://localhost/myurl/phpFile.php", { mrData: jsonArrFinal })
 .done( data => $("#sendResult").html(data) );
```

Comment: I've tried with post too, please se the question edited. @Quentin

Comment: @KevinRodriguez yeah, you used POST, but you are still appending it as a GET parameter on the querystring. It needs to be in the body like the example in the answer above.

Comment: @Quentin tryed now but its not adding the parameter in the url

Comment: @KevinRodriguez — Not adding the parameter in the URL **is the point**!